# Ambiguous mapping found when using class multi level @RequestMapping urls

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm getting the following exception if I use multi level urls in class like `@RequestMapping("/api/v0.1")`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'userController'
bean method getUsers()|to {[/api/v0.1]}: There is already 'userController' bean
method getUser(java.lang.String) mapped.
```

It's like the method level mappings doesn't get into consideration at all.
But it's ok if I put `@RequestMapping("/api")` i.e. remove the `/v0.1` part.

Here is the configuration stripped up to the minimal case:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/v0.1")
public class UserController {   

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/{username}")
    @ResponseBody
    public User getUser(@PathVariable String username) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

servlet-context.xml:

```
<!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Forwards requests to the "/" resource to the "welcome" view -->
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="home"/>    

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /assets/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources/ directory -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/" />
```

I'm using spring 3.1. I also tried to set `alwaysUseFullPath` property to true of the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` bean but it didn't change the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very interesting issue - I checked what could be going on, you are right the "v0.1" is really throwing off the `org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher` which creates the full URI path by combining the path from the controller and the path from the mapped method. If it sees a "file.extension" kind of a pattern in the Controller, then it totally ignores the path mapping of the method - this is the reason why your `@PathVariable` was getting ignored.

I am not sure if this is a bug or intended behavior in Spring MVC, temporary fix would be along what you have already mentioned -

1.To remove "v0.1" from the RequestMapping of Controller and make it without extension say `v0_1`

2.To put this mapping in the mapped method:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {   

    @RequestMapping(value = "/v0.1/users")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/v0.1/users/{username}")
    @ResponseBody
    public User getUser(@PathVariable String username) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I remember trying `@RequestMapping("/api/v01")` on class level (without the dot) and not getting a result but I'll try again and let you know. thanks.

Comment: Since the AntPathMatcher allows regular expressions, I think if you escaped the dot it would work. eg. `v0\.1`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `@RequestMapping(value = "/{version:.*}/users")` to include the dot '.' in the path variable